# How to make a function which multiplies two values

Tags: python, function, operators, multiplication

So, I was writing overly complex answers for simple problems on Codewars as I often do, and one of the problems was,

> Multiply two numbers

It wanted me to put:

```
return a * b
```

But I wanted to make a function that multiplied two numbers by itself, without the help of the '*' operator or any other thing that multiplied values together.

Pretty easy, I thought. I just add the *a* value to some empty value *b* amount of times.

It worked pretty well, up until one of the tests included decimals. I then wrote *this* to get the average of.. well something. That clearly didn't work:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    leftside = 0
    rightside = 0
    average = 0
    for i in range(int(b)):
        leftside += a
    for i in range(int(a)):
        rightside += b
    average = (leftside+rightside) / 2
    return average
```

So basically, what I'm asking is if there's a way to naturally, without any other functions or operators(besides addition and essential things) to multiply values.

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. The question doesn't make any sense, and is reflective of confused thinking. There is only one way in which it can be meaningfully said that a way of writing code is "natural": because it uses the most direct and obvious tool for a simple task. For multiplication, that is `*`. Addition (i.e., using `+`) is exactly as much of an operator as `*` is, and `*` is exactly as "essential" as `+` is. Coming up with complex ways to do things is not natural.

Comment: "up until one of the tests included decimals." Right; you can't do something half a time, and if both values are non-integer, then you can't get around this by swapping which is the iteration variable. Taking an average would *definitely* not help, in any event.

Comment: Multiplication is just repeated addition; that's how it's done "naturally".

Comment: If you are trying to ask "how do I express the 'fact that multiplication is iterated addition' algorithmically, when the values aren't integers?", then *you don't*; multiplication is an *analytic continuation of* addition. It's also really a math question, not a programming question.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree, it's more of a math problem. But I'm still looking for an answer. And back to your first question, I know that. When I say natural, I mean without `*`. I'm just wondering how you would go about doing something like this. Obviously whoever makes a programming language would have to think about this. This question has to have been asked before and there has to be an answer, otherwise `*` wouldn't even be able to function properly, as it had to be programmed too.

Comment: "Obviously whoever makes a programming language would have to think about this." No, they would not, because this has been handled at the hardware level for decades.

Comment: I found a duplicate for you on math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773859/decimal-multiplication-without-multiplication

Comment: How do you the test included decimals without seeing those decimals (in which case you would've include them in your question)?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel just semantics but I think you mean to say compiler/interpreter level?

Comment: Also, where's that problem on codewars, so that we could test potential answers there ourseles?

Comment: I mean hardware level, in the sense that converting `x * y` to machine code does not involve knowing a mulitplication algorithm, it only involves emitting the single machine code opcode that multiplies two register values.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Ah, gotcha

Comment: for integers `a` and `b`: `sum(1 for i in range(a) for j in range(b))`. For decimal you need fractions to express a _mixed numbers_ notation

Answer (score 1):

If you allow division by 2 like your own attempt does, then I guess this might be decent:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    while b >= 1:
        b /= 2
        a += a
    result = 0
    while b:
        b += b
        a /= 2
        if b >= 1:
            result += a
            b -= 1
    return result
```

Or implementing halving myself, without using division:

```
def half(x):
    result = 0
    while x:
        y = 0
        Y = 2.2250738585072014e-308
        while Y + Y <= x:
            y = Y
            Y += Y
        x -= Y
        result += y
    return result

def multiply(a, b):
    while b >= 1:
        b = half(b)
        a += a
    result = 0
    while b:
        b += b
        a = half(a)
        if b >= 1:
            result += a
            b -= 1
    return result
```

Comment: Well.. I guess the way I phrased it allows for this. But division is basically the opposite of multiplication, which means that this process isn't manual, which means I wouldn't consider this the answer.

Comment: @IsaacHeinze Well why did you use it yourself? Also, it's not general division, it's only division by 2. I'd use a bit shift (`>>= 1`, but Python's floats sadly don't support that. I do have another idea, but it's somewhat silly...

Comment: @IsaacHeinze Added a second method, which doesn't use division.